# Display Message from Model Validation Rule

Tags: php, yii

Im having an issue accessing the message's generated by some custom rule in my model..

In the model:

```
public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('active_yn', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('user_name', 'length', 'max'=>20),
            array('password', 'length', 'max'=>100),
            array('full_name', 'length', 'max'=>150),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('user_id, user_name, full_name, active_yn', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
            array('user_name', 'unique', 'on'=>'api_save, insert', 'message'=>'User already in system'),
            array('user_name, full_name', 'required', 'on'=>'api_save', 'message'=>'Required field, {attribute}, is missing'),
        );
    }
```

and in my controller. This is for a REST interface..

```
public function actioncreate(){
        $user = new User();
        $user->scenario = 'api_save';

        // Try to assign POST values to attributes
        if(isset($_POST)){
            foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
                // Does the model have this attribute? If not raise an error
                if($user->hasAttribute($key)){
                    $user->$key = $value;
                }else{
                    $var = array('status'=>500,'body'=>'Parameter <b>'.$key.'</b> is not allowed for model');
                    $send = new sendResponse($var);
                }
            }
        }else{
            $var = array('status'=>500,'body'=>'Parameters required for creation');
            $send = new sendResponse($var);
        }
        if(!$user->validate()){
            $str .= $user->message;
            $var = array('status'=>500,'body'=>$str);
            $send = new sendResponse($var);
        }
        $user->save();
        $var = array('status'=>200,'body'=>CJSON::encode($user));
        $send = new sendResponse($var);
    }
```

If the model doesn't validate i want to display the messages from my model. I have tried `getError` and `getErrors` but i receive an error saying _error is not defined.

Thanks for the help to what is probably a simple question.

Answer (score 1):

After some more searching I found the answer:

```
   if($user->save() === false){
        $str = '';
        foreach ($user->errors as $value) {
            $str .= $value[0]."; ";
        }
        $var = array('status'=>500,'body'=>$str);
        $send = new sendResponse($var);
    }else{
        $var = array('status'=>200,'body'=>CJSON::encode($user));
        $send = new sendResponse($var);
    }
```

I skipped the validation step and just saved the model. If it returned `false` i was then able to pull `$user->errors` as an array or error messages